# Add img to Graphics

Tags: java

I created object shaped Oval like this  :

```
for (toop b : top)
{
    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.fillOval(b.getx(), b.gety(), 50, 50);
}
```

and every thing is fine .
but now i wanna add ball.png instead of setting color for that .
i used this code but nothing changed  :

```
for (toop b : top)
{
    g.drawImage(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\PETTER\\Desktop\\ball.png").getImage(), b.getx() , b.gety() , 50, 50, b);
    g.fillOval(b.getx(), b.gety(), 50, 50);
}
```

So how can i do this ? Help me plz

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why the image isn't showing up, but you probably dont't want to load from a file every time you want to draw the screen.  Load your ImageIcon once at the beginning, and then reference it in g.drawImage().

Comment: And what should to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ever load an image in the `paint()` or `paintComponent()` methods. Do it in a constructor or make a `init()` method. If you are trying to draw the `ball.png` in a frame or panel, do

```
Image ball = null;

private void init()
{
    ball = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader()
                                   .getResource("ball.png")).getImage();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(ball, 0, 0, 100, 100, null);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `g.drawImage(ball, 0, 0, 100, 100, null);` should be `g.drawImage(ball, 0, 0, 100, 100, this);`

Comment: @AndrewThompson I don't think `ImageObserver` is necessary for just drawing images. Isn't it to check for loading and other events when loading it by using a `MediaTracker`?

Comment: It will work fine until someone overrides `init()` & decides to use `MediaTracker`, or decides to provide a constructor where the (possibly asynchronously loaded) image is passed by the user of the API..

Answer (score 0):

If you call fillOval after drawImage the orange color will override the paint.

Also, do not load images with ImageIcons, use ImageLoader.createImage(File) instead. (The return is a BufferedImage that also draws faster)